# Save multiple records in rails and undo if some fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add multiple records at once in rails.

```
tax_rates.map {|tax_rate| TaxRate.new(tax_rate).save }
```

But in this there is the possibility that some records get saved and some are rejected.

Can anyone explain me how to reject all the records if some of the records fail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [“How to ask”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
TaxRate.transaction do
  tax_rates.map do |tax_rate| 
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless TaxRate.new(tax_rate).save
  end
end
```

---

Or for readability reasons you might want to add a new method to your model:

```
# in models/tax_rate.rb
def self.create_all(rates)
  transaction do
    rates.map do |rate| 
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless TaxRate.new(rate).save
    end
  end
end
```

And use it in your controller like this:

```
TaxRate.create_all(tax_rates)
```

Comment: Or just use `create!` or `save!`.

Comment: Can I use transaction in a controller?

Comment: @Avinash142857 Yes.

Comment: Sure you can because `TaxRate.transaction` calls the `transaction` method on the model. But you are right, it might be a good idea to add a method to your model to make the controller method easier to read and understand. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use transactions.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  model1.create!
  model2.create!
  model3.create!
  anything that triggers an exception
  or raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

`` [1] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
[1] pry(main)*   User.create(email: "asfsdaf@spuul.com", password: "asdkfasdlfk")
[1] pry(main)*   Network.create(user_id: 1)
[1] pry(main)* end

   (22.9ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (6.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (24.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'asfsdaf@spuul.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Network. ``

Transactions reset the state of records via rollback. In Rails, rollbacks are only triggered by an exception. **So make sure the methods you're using trigger one**. Some AR methods don't trigger an exception on failure e.g `update_attribute`

For more info regarding this:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

EDIT: Add code, to prove it doesn't silently commit anything on the DB.

Comment: The problem is that your specific example raises an exception and that cancels the whole transaction as desired but if the transaction's block doesn't raise an exception, then there won't be a rollback. So if one of your `create` calls fail because of validations then that failure will be silently ignored; if you used `create!` instead then you'd get exceptions from validation issues and the transaction would work as desired; database errors (such as violating a table constraint that validations don't cover) would raise exceptions and the transaction would work as desired.

Comment: @muistooshort it is worth to mention that there always is an opportunity to `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` ourselves to rollback a transaction.